# Convertendo String para date Swfit 3

Tags: ios, mobile, xcode, swift-3, timezone

Olá, estou tentando converter uma String em Date em Swift 3. Porém a data sempre esta me retornando com duas horas a mais. Segue abaixo meu código.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale =  Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
    let date:Date = dateFormatter.date(from:"12-12-2017 16:49:19")!
```

Saída: **2017-12-28 18:49:19 +0000**

Comment: Aqui parece ok: http://tpcg.io/bhwp9W. Talvez esteja conceituando errado o que precisa fazer ou tem configuração errada no computador Outro: https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a311de352fd1304fcf3a6c0.

Comment: Estranho, pois estou  compilado no iphone e quando pego a timezone, aparece America/Sao Paulo, tudo certinho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que seu código funcione com o `Locale` do BR, é necessário alterar a string `"pt_BR"` para `"pt-br"`, com isso você verá que a exibição da data ficará correta.

Você pode testar melhor esta exibição informando algum valor para a propriedade `timeZone` do dateFormatter, veja o código abaixo:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "pt-br")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let date:Date = dateFormatter.date(from:"12-12-2017 16:49:19")!
```

Neste exemplo, a saída será `-3h (ou -2h no horário de verão)` para a TimeZone que segue o horário de Brasília.